# Looping in DataWeave in MuleSoft

Tags: mule, dataweave

i have a requirement where in i need  to extract the **LoadReferenceNumber** and assign to a  variable which is initiated inside the data weave when the **LoadReferenceNumberType** is **MB**  in mule, below is the xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<CIS>
<LoadReferenceNumberList>
  <LoadReferenceNumberType>MB</LoadReferenceNumberType>
  <LoadReferenceNumber>8070296</LoadReferenceNumber>
 </LoadReferenceNumberList>
 <LoadReferenceNumberList>
  <LoadReferenceNumberType>ACT_SP_DATE</LoadReferenceNumberType>
  <LoadReferenceNumber>20160404T14:12:00</LoadReferenceNumber>
 </LoadReferenceNumberList>
 <LoadReferenceNumberList>
  <LoadReferenceNumberType>SP_DATE</LoadReferenceNumberType>
  <LoadReferenceNumber>20170404T14:12:00</LoadReferenceNumber>
 </LoadReferenceNumberList>
  </CIS>
```

Answer (score 0):

The example below is a dataweave component which extract the LoadReferenceNumber from LoadReferenceNumberList where LoadReferenceNumberType == 'MB':

```
<dw:set-variable variableName="LoadReferenceNumber"><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
value: ((payload.CIS.*LoadReferenceNumberList filter $.LoadReferenceNumberType == 'MB')[0].LoadReferenceNumber) default null]]></dw:set-variable>
        </dw:transform-message>
```

The result is a LinkedHashMap, the example below is logger which logs the LoadReferenceNumber:

```
<logger message="#[flowVars.LoadReferenceNumber.value]" level="INFO"
                doc:name="Logger" />
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: to get plain value in flowVariable instead of LinkedHashMap, change it to below. Notice, I am no longer assigning transformation to 'value'. -  `<dw:set-variable variableName="LoadReferenceNumber"><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
((payload.CIS.*LoadReferenceNumberList filter $.LoadReferenceNumberType == 'MB')[0].LoadReferenceNumber) default null]]></dw:set-variable>
        </dw:transform-message>`. After transformation, `flowVars.LoadReferenceNumber` should hold value.

Comment: Tried this but getting NULL as output.

Comment: can you share your mule configuration.xml? and the exact payload if it's different from the xml above.

Answer (score 0):

you use that data weave

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
value: ((payload.CIS.*LoadReferenceNumberList filter $.LoadReferenceNumberType == 'MB')[0].LoadReferenceNumber) default null
```